# Lookup column to open a URL instead of related item in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, lookup

I have a list with two columns; both are single line of text. The first acts as a URL title and the second one contains the actual URL. Again, both columns are of type single line of text.

Next, I have another list with some columns, including one lookup. That lookup is targeting the second column in the first list, i.e. the single line of text that contais the actual URL. Now, when I click on that lookup field for some list item, a display form is opened showing that related item from the first list. This is a default SharePoint behavior.

I want to be able to open the actual URL instead of opening the lookup item. Is that possible? I prefer the solutions in SharePoint Designer more than coding, but I'll take anything at this point :) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a calculated column to generate HTML with the link, have a look at these articles: 
http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2008/09/01/using-calculated-columns-to-write-html/
http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2008/09/01/apply-color-coding-to-your-sharepoint-lists/